# Como usar group by em LAMBDA

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma tabela produtos:

```
int id
string descricao
int quant
```

Quero fazer o seguinte:

```
select descricao, sum(quant) from produtos group by descricao
```

Como fazer a consulta acima em `lambda`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há duas formas de se fazer:

Direto no linq

```
var result=from p in produto group p by p.descricao into g select new {descricao=g.Key,count=g.Sum(x=>x.quant)}
```

ou com os métodos Extendidos

```
var result = produto.GroupBy(x => x.descricao).Select(new { descricao = g.Key, count = g.Sum(x => x.quant) });
```

Comment: só consegui pegar a `descricao` e a `quant`, caso eu tenha mais campos, como faço para pegá-los?

Comment: É só ir acrescentando os outros campos separado por virgula

Comment: Não consegui :/ Vou criar outra pergunta mostrando como estou fazendo pra ver se você me ajudar.